# Bulk update custom post type at once in WordPress automatically

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have created a custom post type songs which has all the songs and now I want to sort it according to alphabets, which I have done using

```php
function alphaindex_save_alpha( $post_id ) {
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return;
    $slug = 'songs';
    $letter = '';

    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && ( $slug != $_POST['post_type'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;

    $taxonomy = 'alpha';
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) ) {

        $title = strtolower( $_POST['post_title'] );

        // Get the first letter of the title
        $letter = substr( $title, 0, 1 );
    }
    //set term as first letter of post title, lower case
    wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $letter, $taxonomy );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'alphaindex_save_alpha' );
```

now this creates a taxonomy alpha which maps every songs based on the first alphabet for eg. Adele is mapped to A and so on.

I created this alphabet index after I had already put 2000 songs in my word press website and now for the songs to get mapped to the taxonomy I have to individually go to every post page and update the post and only then it appears.

But, **doing this is a very tedious task and want a code that can do it automatically** from the `functions.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `posts_where` filter instead of taxonomy.  You do not need to add any extra data to your database to accomplish this.

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'starts_with_filter');

function starts_with_filter($sql){

  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || ! isset(get_query_var('starts_with')) {
    return $query;
  }

  global $wpdb;

  $startswith = substr ( get_query_var( 'starts_with' ), 0, 1);

  $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE %s ", $startswith.'%' );

  return $sql;
}
```